# Clarifying close vote reasons

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons, vote-to-close, conventions

Due to the close votes on this question: [Transiesta warning (Error on inverting X6/C7 with error: 1)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10430/5) (one of them being an "opinion-based closure" and the other being "needs more focus"), I just wanted to clarify the conventions here.

- ***Opinion-based closures*** are usually for questions like "do you think John Pople really deserved the Nobel Prize in chemistry?" or "should Don Truhlar get a Nobel Prize?". The answers would be much more opinion-based than fact-based.
- "***Needs more focus***" is for when there's more than one question in the post; the subheading says "This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."
- For questions about "What is causing the error?", it is probably something that is a matter of "fact" rather than opinion, although it's possible that the question doesn't have enough detail for a fact-based, and the fact that "guess-work" might be needed to hypothesize the cause of the error, might make it tempting to vote to close based on it being an "opinion-based question", but the more appropriate close vote reason in cases like this is usually "***needs details/clarity.***
- We also have a convention that we keep questions open if they have an answer with a positive net score, see this post (which also explains the reasons): [If a question already has a good answer, does it need to be closed?](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/222/5). So even if the question is opinion-based, needs more focus and needs more clarity/details, we usually would keep the question open since it doesn't do much harm to the side (it doesn't show up in the unanswered queue, and by remaining open, better answers, or better "opinions" can be written more freely). There's better ways to notify the public that the question doesn't conform to our standards (e.g. a banner at the top, like the "want to improve this post?" ones that we often see in the SE network).